# How to duplicate stdin into file

Tags: linux, bash, copy, stdin, tee

I have sophisticated bash script that uses "read -p"(stderr output) very often. And now I need to duplicate all script input from terminal into log file.

```
   tee file.log | script.sh
```

this command does'nt work carefully because ignores output to user.
Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
read -p "input value: " val
echo $val
echo "finish"
```

Terminal run:

```
start
input value: 3
3
finish
```

Tee run:

```
# tee file.log | ./script.sh
start
3
3
finish
```

Comment: are you looking for `script` ? `script file.log; ./script.sh; exit`

Comment: Your question says you want to save user input. `stderr` is output, not input.

Comment: no, i need to log users input, so result file of my example should contain only 3.

Comment: see example, problem is that string "input value" hides(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you're using `tee` here. What I suspect is happening is it needs input, so waits for it, then pipes 3 to stdout

```
-p prompt
Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting
to read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming from a
terminal.
```

However input isn't sent from tty here so prompt is never printed. Still feels very weird for me to use `tee` here, but you can just use `echo -n` instead of the `-p` flag for `read` and it should work.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "start"
echo -n "input value: "
read val
echo $val
echo "finish"
```

e.g.

```
> tee file.log | ./abovescript
start
input value: 3
3
finish

> cat file.log
3
```

Also not sure how to get tee to terminate properly from in-script here, so you need to press return key at end which of course causes newline.

That said, since it's an extra line each time anyway, seems worse than just be doing `echo "$val" >> file.log` each time, though a better option would be just to use a function

```
#!/bin/bash
r() {
  read -p "input value: " val
  echo "$val" >> file.log
  echo "$val"
}

echo "start"
val=$(r)
echo "$val"
echo "finish"
```

Comment: you are right but  maybe there is another way through exec 5>&0 at the beginning of script

Comment: @andr3y How would you use fd 5? Edit: ok I think you mean read from fd 5 into the variable ... might work to print the prompt but you still have the problem of `tee` not terminating properly.

Comment: Example for stdout duplicating: exec 5>&1 npipe=test.pipe trap "rm -f $npipe" EXIT mknod $npipe p tee <$npipe temp.tmp &exec 1>&- exec 1>$npipe

Comment: @andr3y Honestly, you've lost me. Whatever it is, I'm of the opinion that using `tee` like this is way too hackish to ever be practical or where you can ever be positive of the results. function seems simple enough, and if it isn't I might switch to a language that has something like a dedicated `tee` module, ala perl